# How to do regression model selection if dummy variables are involved?

Tags: r, statistics, regression

I am trying to do a logistic regression analysis in R with two continuous explanatory variables and six other explanatory categorical variables, and find a regression model to do predictions. When I do step-wise model selections, there are always some levels of certain categorical variables identified as insignificant. I am just wondering how should I deal with this situation. Should I simply drop these levels, or I should force the program to keep all levels of the categorical variables and try to drop the relatively insignificant variables?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The coefficients / levels are significant or not relative to the reference level of the same variable. To test the overall effect of the variable you can use `anova`. If it is kept in the stepwise selection, its likely has an association.  So, dont start dropping levels.

Comment: I am voting to move this to http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions as it is better suited to receive statistical advice.

Comment: What if (can I ?) I make all levels of the categorical variable "visible", so that the coefficients are not relative to the reference level?

Comment: If one categorical variable is in the model. you could do this by suppressing the intercept,  . But to get the overall effect of the variable you would use `anova`